# Handling File Upload state in React with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am making a form that contains a couple text inputs and one file upload input. I am uncertain how to set the state reflecting an array of what photos have been uploaded. And then how to use the value of said state to make a POST request. In theory, I want to be able to upload a few photos, capture the value of these and set it as the files state and then post the array of info to the endpoint.

```
function NewItem(props) {


const history = useHistory();
  const { classes } = props;
  const { isDarkMode } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const { token } = useContext(LoggedInContext);

  const [itemNameValue, handleItemNameChange, resetItemName] = InputState("");
  const [itemPriceValue, handlePriceChange, resetPriceUrl] = InputState("");
  const [
    itemDescriptionValue,
    handleItemDescriptionChange,
    resetItemDescription
  ] = InputState("");

  const [fileState, setFileState] = useState([]);

  const handleFileUpload = e => {
    setFileState(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const handleNewItemSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch("http://localhost:8181/items", {
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title: itemNameValue,
        price: itemPriceValue,
        description: itemDescriptionValue,
        photos: fileState
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Token: token
      },
      method: "POST"
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        handleSnackbarClick();
      });
  };
  return (
    <PageContent>
      <Navbar />
      <h1 className={classes.heading} style={{ color: isDarkMode && "white" }}>
        New Item
      </h1>
      <form
        className={classes.newForm}
        noValidate
        autoComplete="off"
        onSubmit={handleNewItemSubmit}
      >

        <TextField
          id="outlined-desc"
          label="Facebook Item Description"
          variant="outlined"
          multiline={true}
          rows={4}
          rowsMax={8}
          onChange={handleItemDescriptionChange}
          value={itemDescriptionValue}
          InputLabelProps={{
            classes: {
              root: isDarkMode && classes.cssLabel,
              focused: classes.cssFocused
            }
          }}
          InputProps={{
            classes: {
              root: isDarkMode && classes.cssOutlinedInput,
              focused: classes.cssFocused,
              notchedOutline: isDarkMode && classes.notchedOutline,
              input: isDarkMode && classes.multilineColor
            }
          }}
        />
        <div className={classes.photo_groups}>
          <input
            accept="image/*"
            className={classes.input}
            style={{ display: "none" }}
            id="raised-button-file"
            multiple
            type="file"
            onChange={handleFileUpload}
          />
          <label htmlFor="raised-button-file">
            <Button
              variant="raised"
              component="span"
              className={classes.button}
            >
              Photo Upload
            </Button>
          </label>
          <GroupCheckbox />
        </div>
      </form>
    </PageContent>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [FileReader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to convert the images into base64 strings and send them in the 'POST' data.

Change your `handleFileUpload` function to this -

```
const handleFileUpload = e => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      setFileState(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };
```

`reader.readAsDataURL` reads the contents of your image file and triggers loadend after it is done.

`reader.onloadend` function will set fileState as a base64 string.